# SQL group names as table header rows using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to output a dynamic table using PHP that looks something like this:

```
Paul     56
Paul     6
Paul     78
Paul     34
Paul     76
Mark     56
Mark     5
Mark     34
Mark     87
Mark     23
Mark     765
```

Basically what I want to output is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr colspan="2">Name: Paul</tr>
<tr><td>56</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>78</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>34</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>76><td>Edit</td></tr>

<tr colspan="2">Name: Mark</tr>
<tr><td>56</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>34</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>87</td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>23/td><td>Edit</td></tr>
<tr><td>765/td><td>Edit</td></tr>
</table>
```

What my PHP code looks like so far:

```
<?php
$name_holder = null;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
    if($name_holder != $data[$i]->name){
        $name_holder = $data[$i]->name;
        //not sure what to do here??
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='left'>".$data[$i]->name."</td>";
    echo "<td align='left'>".$data[$i]->hour."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

SQL

```
SELECT name,hour FROM checkin_tbl GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: Please include your code for the actual SQL. So we can help you from the moment data get's in to the moment  and the way you want it rendered

Comment: Could you also add the PHP implementation of the query? Do you use pdo, a ORM, etc etc... is kind of crucial

Comment: replace < by &lt; and > by &gt; in your php code

Comment: @mvbrakel I'm using codeigniter active records for the query. $data is an array of results. Assume first snipet of raw data is in array. $data[$i]->name calls Mark and Paul.

Comment: @Sachink encoding was never the issue with my code. It's more about how to parse thru the the array

Comment: @halfer could you be kind enough to provide me a example please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to group your data at the database level. It is possible to do it that way, but for each group you'd need another `SELECT` to read the related data, and will result in excessive numbers of queries being sent to the database.

I've thus elected to read the data in using a straight query, which would be something like this:

```
SELECT name,hour FROM checkin_tbl ORDER BY name ASC;
```

I've not supplied the database code below, as it is not clear what database you are using (e.g. MySQL) or what interface you are using (e.g. PDO). I've thus emulated a data source using an array - I'm sure you can swap this out with a `fetchAll()` or a `foreach()` and a row `fetch()`.

Thus, try something like this:

```
<?php

// Data from your database
$rawData = [
    ['Paul', 56],
    ['Paul', 6],
    ['Mark', 56],
    ['Mark', 5],
];

// Let's reformat this
$out = [];
foreach ($rawData as $pair)
{
    $name = $pair[0];
    if (!isset($out[$name]))
    {
        $out[$name] = [];
    }

    // Pop the value on the list
    $out[$name][] = $pair[1];
}

// Use this to look at your structure
#print_r($out);

?>

<!-- Here's your rendering section -->

<?php foreach ($out as $name => $data): ?>
    <tr colspan="2"><td>Name: <?php echo htmlentities($name) ?></td></tr>

    <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo htmlentities($item) ?></td><td>Edit</td></tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

My strategy is to format the data as much as possible outside of the template - your code and another answer here (at the time of writing) are mixing logic and layout excessively in my opinion, and you need to separate them out.

This is why I have switched to opening/closing PHP tags in the rendering section: this is broadly HTML with PHP snippets where dynamic output is required. You'll benefit from tag matching and syntax colouration in your IDE if you do it this way.

I've added `htmlentities()` in to protect against XSS.

Comment: I completely agree with all of your above comments. In no way did i intent to 'compete' with your answer. I even stated it was a better setup did I not? I now even removed my answer as yours is way more complete in the way it has fully answered the question now.

Comment: Fair enough, @mvbrakel - no need to remove your answer though! Seeing many ways to solve the same problem may be useful to the OP, both here and generally. (I'll delete a couple of comments above to tidy up - thanks again for the feedback).

Comment: No problem @BaconJuice. I've fixed some invalid HTML too, see my edit just now.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the desired situation, there is absolutely no need for a GROUP BY.
In fact this is actually hindering your from displaying all records for a given person. You will end up with one row per person, filled with the last record for that person.

In order to get the situation you desire, strip the GROUP BY. 
A PHP solution COULD be.

```
$name_holder = null;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
    if($name_holder != $data[$i]->name){
        $name_holder = $data[$i]->name;
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>Name: " . $name_holder . "</td></tr>"
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='left'>".$data[$i]->hour."</td>";
    echo "<td align='left'>edit</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

You were well on the way to a correct solution.

### Background info on Grouping and your problem:

A good explanation is found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm
A demo that it will not work can be tested on the w3schools demo database: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby

All records:

```
SELECT CustomerId, ShipperId FROM [Orders] WHERE ShipperId = 1
```

Grouped:

```
SELECT CustomerId, ShipperId FROM [Orders] WHERE ShipperId = 1 GROUP BY ShipperId
```